Creating an Infinite Slider with Xamarin.Android
I need to create a slider that can be used to select any integer value, from -infinity to +infinity. The slider would have a thumb that stayed in the center and the user would slide the background (the track, ticks & tick labels) left or right. I have thought about using a pager-like View and modifying it to look like a slider, and using the selected index as the current value, but I'm not sure if this would be efficient, not to mention a lot of extra work could backfire since I would be using a complex View for an unintended purpose. I am currently using com.google.android.material.slider.Slider for my sliders with constant start & end values (although I still haven't figured out how to customize the ticks, which would be a very significant part of an infinite slider). Does anybody know of any good ways to create or simulate an infinite slider?
